# partprobe equivalent on OS X

Tags: partition, osx, gpt

After I manually edited a partition table on a device in OS X, the corresponding devices don't get created automatically under /dev. 
How to I tell the OS X kernel to reread partition tables as I would do this with `partprobe` on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is to eject the disk and reinsert it.  You can run

```
diskutil eject /dev/disk1
```

in terminal, changing the 1 in `/dev/disk1` to the disk number of the drive in question.